# Como renomear o banco de dados (RData) no R?

Tags: banco-de-dados, r

Tenho a seguinte situação: preciso fazer um merge de dois bancos. O nome de ambos os arquivos do banco são: `banco2.RData` e `banco2_2.rdata`

Entretanto, quando abro os bancos no R eles têm o mesmo nome: `banco2`, na verdade nem abrem no mesmo ambiente, por causa da duplicidade de nomes. Por conta disso não consigo fazer o merge.

Assim, como posso alterar o nome `banco2` referente à base de dados que é aberta no R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Carregue o arquivo `banco2_2.rdata` no `R`. Use o comando

```
banco2_2 <- banco2
```

para criar o data frame `banco2_2`. Carregue o arquivo `banco2.RData` no `R`. O `banco2` antigo será substituído. Faça o merge entre `banco2_2` e `banco2`.

Comment: Marcus Nunes, agradeço sua ajuda. Deu certo!

Answer (score 3):

Realmente isso é um problema dos dados em formato `.rdata`, pois você não sabe o que tem dentro do arquivo e eles podem sobrescrever várias coisas. Se você fizer isso manualmente pode ser bem complicado, você vai ter que ler um arquivo, renomear todos os objetos, depois ler o outro arquivo e assim por diante.

Uma solução é não carregar seus arquivos na sua área de trabalho principal. Você cria um um ambiente separado e carrega os arquivos lá. Vou dar um exemplo.

Vamos criar dois arquivos `.rda` de exemplo que contém objetos com o mesmo nome:

```
rm(list = ls())
save(mtcars, iris, file = "dados1.rda")
save(mtcars, iris, file = "dados2.rda")
```

Agora suponha que você queira ler esses arquivos mas não queira que os objetos sejam sobrescritos.

A primeira coisa que você tem que fazer é criar um ambiente novo (é como se fosse uma lista):

```
dados1 <- new.env()
```

E agora na hora de dar `load()` você vai falar para dar `load()` nesse ambiente.

```
load("dados1.rda", envir = dados1)
```

Se você quiser acessar os dados você acessa como se fosse uma lista:

```
dados1$iris
dados1$mtcars
```

Agora você pode ler o `dados2.rda` sem sobrescrever os objetos do `dados1`:

```
dados2 <- new.env()
load("dados2.rda", envir = dados2)
```

Se você não quiser trabalhar com `environments` você pode transformá-los em lista:

```
dados1 <- as.list(dados1)
```

Mas se você estiver passando muito por esse problema, talvez seja uma boa ideia salvar os arquivos no formato `.rds` pois assim você pode ler com o nome que quiser, sem ter que fazer essa ginástica toda.

Comment: Muito obrigada, Carlos!!!