# Leitura de RDatas que retornam datas frames com nomes diferentes

Tags: r

Preciso ler uma lista de 17 `RDATA`s cada um deles retorna um `data.frame`, mas alguns desses data frames possuem nomes diferentes (não sei extamente quais) o que atrapalharia o código abaixo

```
lapply(caminhoArquivosPensao, function(x){
  load(x)
  base.pensionistas.semduplicadas$DATA.ADMISSÃO.SERVIDOR.FALECIDO <- dmy(base.pensionistas.semduplicadas$DATA.ADMISSÃO.SERVIDOR.FALECIDO)
  base.pensionistas.semduplicadas$DT_OBITO_INSTITUIDOR <- dmy(base.pensionistas.semduplicadas$DT_OBITO_INSTITUIDOR)
  base.pensionistas.semduplicadas$DT_AFASTAMENTO <- dmy(base.pensionistas.semduplicadas$DT_AFASTAMENTO)
  base.pensionistas.semduplicadas$DT_IMPLANTACAO <- dmy(base.pensionistas.semduplicadas$DT_IMPLANTACAO)

  base.pensionista <- base.pensionistas.semduplicadas %>%
    filter(DT_OBITO_INSTITUIDOR >= dmy("09/06/2017")) %>%
    mutate(DIAS.RECEB = difftime(DT_AFASTAMENTO, DT_IMPLANTACAO, units = c("days"))) %>%
    filter(DIAS.RECEB <=120)
})
```

O data.frame `base.pensionistas.semduplicadas` são os mais recentes, que eu fiz já com os nomes padronizados. Como atribuir a uma variável qualquer (neste caso um data.frame) a base lida de um RData independente do seu nome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem algumas soluções possíveis. A mais recomendada delas é para de usar arquivos `.RData` e usar aquivos `.rds` pois eles não alteram o ambiente e ajudam a tornar os problemas reprodutíveis.

Antes de mais nada, vamos criar arquivos `.RData`.

```
save(mtcars, file = "arquivo1.RData")
iris <- dplyr::rename(iris, cyl = Sepal.Length)
save(iris, file = "arquivo2.RData")

# Voltar ao ambiente vazio
rm(list=ls())
ls()
#> character(0)
```

Como contornas a questão sem mudar para arquivos `.rds`:

### Pela mudança gerada no mundo

```r
arquivos <- dir(pattern = "\\.RData$")

extrair_cyl <- function(x) {
  mundo_antigo <- ls()
  load(x)
  mundo_novo <- ls() # ele vai pegar mundo_antigo além do objeto carregado
  nome_objeto <- mundo_novo[!mundo_novo %in% c(mundo_antigo, "mundo_antigo")]
  df <- get(nome_objeto)
  df$cyl
}

extrair_cyl(arquivos[1])
#>  [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
extrair_cyl(arquivos[2])
#>   [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4 4.6 5.0 4.4 4.9 5.4 4.8 4.8 4.3 5.8 5.7 5.4
#>  [18] 5.1 5.7 5.1 5.4 5.1 4.6 5.1 4.8 5.0 5.0 5.2 5.2 4.7 4.8 5.4 5.2 5.5
#>  [35] 4.9 5.0 5.5 4.9 4.4 5.1 5.0 4.5 4.4 5.0 5.1 4.8 5.1 4.6 5.3 5.0 7.0
#>  [52] 6.4 6.9 5.5 6.5 5.7 6.3 4.9 6.6 5.2 5.0 5.9 6.0 6.1 5.6 6.7 5.6 5.8
#>  [69] 6.2 5.6 5.9 6.1 6.3 6.1 6.4 6.6 6.8 6.7 6.0 5.7 5.5 5.5 5.8 6.0 5.4
#>  [86] 6.0 6.7 6.3 5.6 5.5 5.5 6.1 5.8 5.0 5.6 5.7 5.7 6.2 5.1 5.7 6.3 5.8
#> [103] 7.1 6.3 6.5 7.6 4.9 7.3 6.7 7.2 6.5 6.4 6.8 5.7 5.8 6.4 6.5 7.7 7.7
#> [120] 6.0 6.9 5.6 7.7 6.3 6.7 7.2 6.2 6.1 6.4 7.2 7.4 7.9 6.4 6.3 6.1 7.7
#> [137] 6.3 6.4 6.0 6.9 6.7 6.9 5.8 6.8 6.7 6.7 6.3 6.5 6.2 5.9
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

### Use o poder dos ambientes

A abordagem está descrita [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/188231/43953) e consiste em carregar a tabela em um ambiente isolado e depois trazer a tabela para uma variável.

```r
arquivos <- dir(pattern = "\\.RData$")

extrair_cyl2 <- function(x) {
  novo_ambiente <- new.env()
  load(x, novo_ambiente)
  nome_objeto <- names(novo_ambiente)
  df <- novo_ambiente[[nome_objeto]]
  df$cyl
}

extrair_cyl2(arquivos[1])
#>  [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
extrair_cyl2(arquivos[2])
#>   [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4 4.6 5.0 4.4 4.9 5.4 4.8 4.8 4.3 5.8 5.7 5.4
#>  [18] 5.1 5.7 5.1 5.4 5.1 4.6 5.1 4.8 5.0 5.0 5.2 5.2 4.7 4.8 5.4 5.2 5.5
#>  [35] 4.9 5.0 5.5 4.9 4.4 5.1 5.0 4.5 4.4 5.0 5.1 4.8 5.1 4.6 5.3 5.0 7.0
#>  [52] 6.4 6.9 5.5 6.5 5.7 6.3 4.9 6.6 5.2 5.0 5.9 6.0 6.1 5.6 6.7 5.6 5.8
#>  [69] 6.2 5.6 5.9 6.1 6.3 6.1 6.4 6.6 6.8 6.7 6.0 5.7 5.5 5.5 5.8 6.0 5.4
#>  [86] 6.0 6.7 6.3 5.6 5.5 5.5 6.1 5.8 5.0 5.6 5.7 5.7 6.2 5.1 5.7 6.3 5.8
#> [103] 7.1 6.3 6.5 7.6 4.9 7.3 6.7 7.2 6.5 6.4 6.8 5.7 5.8 6.4 6.5 7.7 7.7
#> [120] 6.0 6.9 5.6 7.7 6.3 6.7 7.2 6.2 6.1 6.4 7.2 7.4 7.9 6.4 6.3 6.1 7.7
#> [137] 6.3 6.4 6.0 6.9 6.7 6.9 5.8 6.8 6.7 6.7 6.3 6.5 6.2 5.9
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Os ambientes também podem ser transformados em listas com `as.list(novo_ambiente)` e depois ser manipulado normalmente (usando 1 como índice, por exemplo).